# Power a number with input() and function within class

Tags: python, oop, methods

I'm able to calculate area of square without using class/method but when I want to add it to the class if it is failing on line 8 with the following error:

> area() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were  given

My code try is:

```
class Square():
    def area(side_length):
        calc = side_length**2
        return calc

figure = Square()
side_length = int(input("Enter side length: "))
print(figure.area(side_length))
```

If I run this code, it works fine. I think I'm doing smth wrong in calling methods:

```
def area(side_length):
        calc = side_length**2
        return calc
side_length = int(input("Enter side length: "))
area(side_length)
```

Comment: You forgot to give `area` a `self` parameter.

Comment: Also, `side_length` should probably be an attribute of the `Square`, passed into the constructor. Otherwise there is no point having a class.

Comment: `def area(self, side_length):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Square():
    def area(self, side_length):
        calc = side_length**2
        return calc

figure = Square()
side_length = int(input("Enter side length: "))
print(figure.area(side_length))
```

please mind that in python, every instance method has at least one argument, for example there. when you call `figure.area`, you are passing two parameters to `area` method:

1. `figure object` (that is always first parameter)
2. `side_length`

so when you are defining an instance method, you must set a parameter for `figure object` even if you don't use it... It can have any name you want, but it is highly recommended to use `self` and it is a contract. `self` refers to `figure`

Comment: Thanks! Marking this answer as right one because of additional information provideed

Answer (score 2):

You're missing `self`:

```py
class Square():
    def area(self, side_length):
        calc = side_length**2
        return calc

figure = Square()
side_length = int(input("Enter side length: "))
print(figure.area(side_length))
```

Remember, in Python OOP, every single function need to have self parameter.

Comment: While here `self` is necessary, there exist also static methods that although being part of a class, they don't need the `self` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

All class methods [(which are not decorated with `@staticmethod` or `@classmethod`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod) need a `self` parameter:

```py
class Square:
    def area(self, side_length):
        calc = side_length ** 2
        return calc

figure = Square()
side_length = int(input("Enter side length: "))
print(figure.area(side_length))
```

But, [as mentioned in the comments by Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73386906/power-a-number-with-input-and-function-within-class#comment129600447_73386906), there is no real point in having the class if you don't do something like this:

```py
class Square:
    def __init__(self, side_length):
        self.side_length = side_length
    def area(self):
        calc = self.side_length ** 2
        return calc

side_length = int(input("Enter side length: "))
figure = Square(side_length)
print(figure.area())
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot self parameter

```
class Square():
def area(self, side_length):
    calc = side_length**2
    return calc

figure = Square()
side_length = int(input("Enter side length: "))
print(figure.area(side_length))
```